# Como utilizar uma propriedade de uma tag, usando JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho um componente preenchido dinamicamente

```
<select id="selectTeste">
    <option value='1' exigeIdade='true'>item 1</option>
    <option value='2' exigeIdade='true'>item 2</option>
    <option value='3' exigeIdade='false'>item 3</option>
    <option value='4' exigeIdade='true'>item 4</option>
</select>
```

e tenho uma função jquery que precisa usar a propriedade `exigeIdade`, ex:

```
//se alterar o comboProcedimento, verifica a idade
    $("#selectTeste").on("change", function () {
        atualizaProfissional(exigeIdade); //Como pegar a propriedade exigeIdade?
    });
```

Como fazer para enviar a propriedade exigeIdade via parâmetro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use o [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) do HTML

Para acessar um valor de um attributo do tipo data usando jQuery use `$('elemento').data('nome-atributo')`

```js
$("#selectTeste").on("change", function() {
  var exigeIdade = $("#selectTeste option:selected").data('exige-idade');
  console.log(exigeIdade);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectTeste">
    <option value='1' data-exige-idade='true'>item 1</option>
    <option value='2' data-exige-idade='true'>item 2</option>
    <option value='3' data-exige-idade='false'>item 3</option>
    <option value='4' data-exige-idade='true'>item 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No caso, basta eu acrescentar a palavra `data-` antes do nome do meu atributo? pode ser `data-exigeIdade`?

Comment: Pode ser `data-exigeIdade` sim, mas note que escrevi `data-exige-idade`, pois o HTML é case insensitive, e no momento de recuperar esse valor você terá que usar o nome todo em lower case, dessa maneira - `.data('exigeidade')`. Por isso usei `exige-idade`, além de ser uma boa prática para escrever tags/propriedades em html. :)

Comment: entendi, obrigado

Comment: Funcionou de boa em html simples, mas quando uso esse código no `bootstrap-select` não funciona. Alguma dica?

Comment: erro meu, deu certo sim.

Answer (score 4):

Tente assim:

```
$("#selectTeste").on("change", function () {
    var ExigeIdade = $("#selectTeste").find(":selected").attr("exigeIdade");
    atualizaProfissional(ExigeIdade);
});
```